# Возможен ли вывод средств с upwork?

Tags: upwork

**UPD** Вопрос потерял актуальность. На 08.03.2022 Upwork прекратил регистрацию новых аккаунтов в России и Беларуси, а старые будут приостановлены до 01.05.2022. Upwork всё.

На сайте upwork обновилось предупреждение. Цитирую.

> На данный момент мы хотим отметить следующие важные ограничения:
>
> PayPal, MasterCard и Visa не будут продолжать обслуживать клиентов в России, и другие финансовые учреждения могут внести аналогичные изменения в отношении России и Беларуси, и мы направим уведомление, когда сможем это сделать.
>
> Географические санкции не ограничивают вас в работе с фрилансерами или клиентами в Украине, России или Беларуси, за исключением случаев, когда клиент находится в регионе Донбасса Украины, описанном в Указе президента Байдена как “так называемая Донецкая Народная Республика (ДНР) или Луганская Народная Республика (ЛНР) регионы Украины”.

Как понимать данное сообщение? Я читаю, работать российские фрилансеры могут, а вывести средства - нет.

Если кто-то разбирается в теме или уже столкнулся с проблемами вывода, прошу поделиться информацией или прокомментировать.

Comment: Несколько дней назад читал, что paypal нормально работает. В прочем не знаю, как на нём сказались запреты визы и мастеркарда. А там это единственные способы вывода? Может есть и другие? Электронные кошельки или карта мир?

Comment: "We strongly recommend that you withdraw this balance to your preferred payment method on file, in order to ensure access to your funds.
Important: The ability to log in to your Upwork account will be restricted effective 31 May 2022." (c) Upwork mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я читаю, работать российские фрилансеры могут, а вывести средства - нет.

*Слегка* (сильно "слегка") не так

1. Не работают трансграничные карточные платежи MC, Visa, AmEx (но работает "Мир" в 18 странах и UnionPay китайский в 180(?))
2. Практически все платежные системы (и "электронные кошельки") блокируют русские переводы

НО

Wire-transfers (читай "Свифт-платежи") могут проходить (формально) на счета в банках, не включенных в санкционный лист

[С учетом](https://community.upwork.com/t5/Upwork-Helps-Blog/Updates-Relating-to-Recent-Events-in-Eastern-Europe/ba-p/1023195#toc-hId-77646721)

> I am in Russia, can I let my funds stay on Upwork?
>
> It appears that certain affected financial institutions are likely to
> be removed from SWIFT, which means that we will not be able to
> transfer funds to those financial institutions in Russia or their
> subsidiaries. Freelancers may leave their funds on Upwork for up to
> 180 days if the funds are less than USD $1000 and 90 days if your
> funds are USD $1000 or more. We will continue to assess our policies
> as we learn more about the invasion of Ukraine.

это может быть пока выходом, а там "или ишак, или падишах, или заговорит"

Comment: Действительно, есть пока что два варианты прямого перевода. С хранением средств на внутреннем счёте Upwork тоже ясно - вечно там хранить деньги никто не будет, нужно вовремя вывести.

Answer (score 0):

На 7-е марта сам Upwork рекомендует для России прямой перевод в рублях:

> Recommended for Russia
> Direct to Local Bank (RUB)
> $0.99 USD per withdrawal
> Deposit to your local bank account in RUB

Также доступен прямой перевод в долларах:

> Wire Transfer (USD)
> $30 USD per wire to any bank
> Up to 7 business days to receive funds

Comment: Direct to Local Bank, скорее всего, идёт через SWIFT (на следующем шаге предлагают ввести Bank Code), и многие банки от этой системы уже отключили.